# Cannot install from npm offline registry

Tags: npm

I've been trying to do this forever to no avail, please help...

We work on a virtualized developement environment that is completely cutoff from the world, with no internet connection whatsoever...

We have a Sonotype Nexus repository server setup on one of the VMs that is proven to work, has it currently serves Maven packages

Now i'm trying to set it up to serve NPM packages, without success, which is the same amount of success i had with sinopia, npm-offline, etc... So clearly the problem is with my npm client configuration.

So after having set my registry configuration to our private repository, anything i do (install, adduser, etc.) fails with a 407, which seems to indicate a problem with proxy configuration... Problem is, being completely offline, there's no proxy configuration to be had!

Surely there's some obscure npm configuration somewhere to disable that proxy check?

I'm at a loss to be honest, please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `npm config list` ?

Comment: ah there you go... i naively thought that installing a fresh, up-to-date node/npm would wipe my configuration, which it did not... turns out i had leftover proxy configuration from another life.